# How to change the size of a tool window in ArcMap 10.7

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, tools

I'm doing a ton of Attribute Transferring utilizing the Spatial Adjustment toolbar.
[image: Spatial Adjustment Toolbar]

When I use the Attribute Transfer Tool it opens a select a source feature window
[image: Select a Source Feature]

and the Select a Destination Feature window
[image: Select a Destination Feature]

Is there a way to have these windows open in a different size. I need to see an attribute that is far down the list.

Comment: The ArcMap windows are notorious for not being resizeable (with a few exception) this is an aspect where the newer ArcGIS PRO is indeed better. As ArcMap 10.7 is not the latest (it's 10.8) and as support for ArcMap will soon end you may consider switching to PRO...

Comment: These two windows appear to be resizable, or at least there's a drag handle visible in the lower right corner. Whether they remember their sizes the next time is a different question. I haven't tried.